# Date data type not preserved in Snowflake to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table that includes a date field.

When I query Snowflake and load the data into a Pandas dataframe the date is always converted to object data type in the Pandas dataframe.

I've tried lots of options, at the moment I'm using this

```
snowflake_url = f'snowflake://{sf_user}:{sf_password}@{sf_account}/{sf_database}/{sf_schema}?warehouse={sf_warehouse}'
engine = create_engine(snowflake_url)
query = f"SELECT * FROM {sf_table}"

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)

print(df.dtypes)
```

Table currently contains data types of object, integer and float that are preserved properly but dates are being converted to object as well.

I don't really want to nominate individual field names, because I'm trying to make the script dynamic for lots of tables but I will if that's the only solution.

Comment: [Snowflake to Pandas Data Mapping](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas#snowflake-to-pandas-data-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the dates into pandas datetime, you can do

```
df['the_column_name_for_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['the_column_name_for_date'])
```

Here's the link for documentation

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).